# Host custom website on Shopify domain name

Tags: shopify, web-hosting

My client has a Domain name that he bought from Shopify, is it possible for me to host the website I for him on that domain name ? or do I need to transfer that domain name to a different registrar and then use it ?

Answer (score 0):

Helo there, please provide us more detail, like what is the domain name, what kind of website would you like to host, ect.

If you have a Custom Domain, you will need to transfer it out of Shopify in order to change its nameservers. I recommend transferring it to Namecheap for their cheap prices and amazing customer service. If you don't need to change nameservers for the new host (So you only need to change/add "A" "TXT" "AAAA" "SRV" and/or "CNAME" records), you have the option to keep it in Shopify or to transfer it elsewhere.

More information about DNS on Shopify custom domains: help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/domains/managing-domains/advanced-settings